# Which Stack Exchange site is the most suitable to ask questions about garbage management?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I’ve looked at [Earth Science](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/tour), [Biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tour), and [Sustainable Living](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/tour).

Unfortunately, I’m not a contributing member to either of the sites, so I have little idea where my question would be a good fit. It’s about (large-scale) techniques to tackle organic waste through insects.

I thought Earth Science would be a good fit but it seems focused on geophyics. Sustainable Living seems to focus on individuals. Biology may know about insects but not their use in garbage management.

Is there a site where it’s appropriate to post this question? If not, are there any proposed sites on Area 51?

Comment: Thanks for digging through to find that. I've posted my question on sustainable-living.SE, I'll wait to see how it's received.

Comment: Oh, ...must. not...must not...must not....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’m turning my original comment into an answer as I gain more evidence and thus more confidence that **[Sustainable Living](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is the right site** for your question.

> Sustainable-living.SE seems to focus on individuals

They seem to accept questions like:

- [Did any country, city, or village implement a coffee separate collection with success?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/9996)
- [Is there any cold-resistant anaerobic bacteria for biodigestion?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/224)
- [Are there any experiences with small-scale duckweed farming using domestic wastes or wastewater?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/1141)

The *Related* sections on these pages show more questions like these.

Some of them focus on scientific research or empirical data related to biodegradable waste and some of them have a question pattern of “Has *X* ever been used for *Y*”.

Their [help center](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) lists *“Product and appliance life-cycles, **waste streams** and waste minimisation”* as on-topic.
I cannot find any discussion about waste management *being off-topic* on their meta.

As the site still isn’t quite mature, I cannot find a question like yours that has a negative score; the few questions about waste that are closed don’t seem to have specific off-topic reasons — it’s just general stuff like “needs more details” or “needs more focus”, but *never* anything akin to “questions about biodegradable waste techniques are off-topic here”.

They have a [*waste* tag](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/tags/waste/info) and a [*biodegradable-waste* tag](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/biodegradable-waste) which you could use for your question (which is here: [Are there any insect-based waste-separation techniques?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/10071) — currently at score 2 with one answer, which looks great).

---

[Biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) doesn’t list your type of question as off-topic, but the closest on-topic item in their help center is *“general questions about biological concepts”*.
They don’t have waste-related tags, currently.
Biology doesn’t look like the best candidate.

And [Earth Science](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is really more focused on geo-science.
Quickly glancing through some of the questions on that site, I can’t find anything similar to your question there.